# Normal Distribution/Standard Deviation

Tags: c

My Instructions: Write a program that starts out asking the user for the mean u and standard deviation s for the normal distribution (see the [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) )

The program then asks for an N, and then asks for N values x. For each x it writes out `f(x)` to the screen. Note that the program asks the user for u, s, and N just once. After that it asks for N values for x, one by one. After each value x it writes out the corresponding value of the function.

What I am confused about is what the **N** is supposed to stand for.  I assumed it was number of x's but can anyone clarify this for me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES 
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
double u,s, N, x1,math1, math2, math3,n, v, x;

printf("Enter Mean: ");
scanf("%lf", &u);
printf("Enter Standard Deviation: ");
scanf("%lf", &s);
printf("Enter number of x's: ");
scanf("%lf", &N);

    for (v=1; v<=N; v++)
    {
    printf("Enter Value: ");
    scanf("%lf", &x);
    n=(-1/2);
    printf("f(x)= ");
    math1 =1/(u*sqrt(2*M_PI));
    math2= (x-u)/s * (x-u)/s;
    math3= M_E * exp(n);
    x1 = math1 * exp(math3)*exp(math2);
    printf("%lf  \n", x1);
    }
system("Pause");
}
```

Comment: Well by reading your assignment I would think it's exactly what you were guessing. The number of the values. But maybe you should ask the one who gave you the assignment? He/she can tell you that for sure. Edit: I'm also not sure why you tagged this with 'C' as it's obviously not a question in programming?

Comment: Please fix the indention before posting any code.

Comment: @user2023608 I just added the tag normal-distribution. Didn't dare to remove the 'c' tag as maybe I'm overseeing something

Comment: I think your `math1` assignment is incorrect.  Normal distributions can have a mean of zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`N` stands for number of inputs

pretty much clear from this part:
`for (v=1; v<=N; v++)`

Comment: Ok thank you that's what I thought it was but wasn't 100% sure

Answer (score 1):

If your instructions are as given, then N does indeed stand for the number of *x* values required.

Your program does just that, asking for *N* values of *x*.

First, it declares a variable *N* at the start of the program:

```
double u,s, N, x1,math1, math2, math3,n, v, x;
```

Then it prompts for input as an integer:

```
printf("Enter number of x's: ");
scanf("%lf", &N);
```

...and finally uses that integer to read in *N* values for *x*.

```
for (v=1; v<=N; v++)
{
```

Comment: Those were the only instructions given to me but I am always up for some advice :)